# User formatting for textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

A perfect example is stackoverflow. When a user types a question, the textarea give the user basic formatting options such as bullet points, numbering, italicize, etc. How can I create a similar textarea? I am currently using html, css and php.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript (or more effectively jQuery) to create your own textarea with this behaviour, or look at an existing package such as TinyMCE and configure it to meet your requirements (the approach I would suggest): http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use an editor like TinyMCE: http://www.tinymce.com/

There are others as well, but TinyMCE is what I see used most.